# unix 環境で、 ascii diagram を作成・編集したい

Tags: unix

http://www.rtpro.yamaha.co.jp/RT/FAQ/IP-Filter/apply-filter-to-interface.html

yamaha のルーターについての資料を読んでいました。ここで、その処理のフローが以下に抜粋する通り、 ascii の diagram にて表現されていました。

```
                    :
             [BRI]  : ISDN回線 or 専用線
                    :
  +-----------------+-------------------+
  |                 |                   |
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |  |     PPPやISDN回線の処理     |    |
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |                 |                   |
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |  |       パケット・キュー      |    | …優先制御や帯域制御を使う/使える時
  |  |      (↓)    +----(↑)----+ |    | queue class filter ...
  |  |              |   queue    | |    | pp queue type ...
  |  |      (↓)    +----(↑)----+ |    | pp queue class filter list ...
  |  +-----------------------------+    | pp queue class property ...
  |                 |                   |
  |                 |       ＜外側＞    |
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |  |      NATディスクリプタ      |    | nat descriptor ...
  |  |  +-(1)-+-(2)-+-(3)-+-(4)-+  |    | ip pp nat descriptor ...
  |  |  | ▲  | ▲  | ▲  | ▲  |  |    |
  |  |  +-----+-----+-----+-----+  |    |
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |                 |       ＜内側＞    |
  |                 |                   |
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |  |         IPフィルタ          |    |
  |  | +----(↓)----+----(↑)----+ |    | ip filter ...
  |  | |     in     |    out     | |    | ip pp secure filter in/out ....
  |  | +----(↓)----+----(↑)----+ |    | 
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |                 |                   |
  |              (PP#n)                 | ip pp local address
  |                 |                   |
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |  |       IPルーティング        |    |
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |                 |                   |
  |               (LAN)                 | ip lan address
  |                 |                   |
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |  |         IPフィルタ          |    |
  |  | +----(↑)----+----(↓)----+ |    | ip filter ...
  |  | |     in     |    out     | |    | ip lan secure filter in/out ....
  |  | +----(↑)----+----(↓)----+ |    | 
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |                 |                   |
  |                 |       ＜内側＞    |
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |  |      NATディスクリプタ      |    | nat descriptor ...
  |  |  +-(1)-+-(2)-+-(3)-+-(4)-+  |    | ip lan nat descriptor ...
  |  |  | ▼  | ▼  | ▼  | ▼  |  |    |
  |  |  +-----+-----+-----+-----+  |    |
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |                 |       ＜外側＞    |
  |                 |                   |
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |  |       パケット・キュー      |    | …優先制御や帯域制御を使う/使える時
  |  |      (↑)    +----(↓)----+ |    | queue class filter ...
  |  |              |   queue    | |    | lan queue type ...
  |  |      (↑)    +----(↓)----+ |    | lan queue class filter list ...
  |  +-----------------------------+    | lan queue class property ...
  |                 |                   |
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |  |     イーサネットの処理      |    |
  |  +-----------------------------+    |
  |                 |                   |
  +-----------------+-------------------+
                    |
             [LAN]  |
                    |
  ------------------+--------------------
```

もし、このような diagram が比較的簡単に作成できるのであれば、例えば複雑なソースコードにコメント上で注釈として、このような diagram を記しておくことで、以降の実装者がコードの理解がしやすくなり、なので有意義なのではないか、と思いました。

## 質問

unix cli の環境で、 ascii 図形を作成/編集を効率的に行なおうとする際に、定番のツール・ライブラリはありますか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markdown(など)にシーケンス図やフローチャートを組み込む場合, [Graphviz (dot言語)](https://graphviz.org/), [PlantUML](https://plantuml.com/ja/), [Mermaid](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/) … などが有名です。

一部は Ascii出力も可能なので, dot言語や PlantUMLを使ったことがあるのなら簡単なはず

- PlantUML [ascii-art 出力](https://plantuml.com/ja/ascii-art)
- Graphviz

  - [dot-to-ascii](https://github.com/ggerganov/dot-to-ascii)
  - stackoverflow.com: [Graphviz and ascii output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211801/graphviz-and-ascii-output)

    - `Graph::Easy` package
    - その他 (未確認)

その他に, Ascii図を直接描いて出力を得る方法もあります

- 記事: [アスキーアートでフローのダイアグラムを作成できる「Asciiflow」](https://gigazine.net/news/20140123-asciiflow/)

   => http://asciiflow.com/